# Updating multiple elements without materializing in MongoDB .Net library

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have an **IDataAccess** interface which is supposed to be an interface for data access layer agnostic to database software. So, say, you want to use MongoDB, you create a class that implements IDataAccess then inject it to any project who uses/expects an IDataAccess. so switching between databases becomes easy.

Everything works perfectly with an exception for updating multiple elements. **IDataAccess** has a method for updating multiple elements, so it takes a query and an action to update elements. I need to find a way to convert this to MongoUpdate so MongoDB does both querying and updating. Right now, I materialize IQueryable meaning that I get the result back from the database, then I make the changes and save them back. This could lead to a performance disaster. I want MongoDB to do the update so I need to find a way create a MongoUpdate from agnostic arguments. Any idea how this can be achieved?

I can change the arguments in IDataAccess as long as they're still agnostic to databases.

IDataAccess: https://github.com/peymanmortazavi/Hangout/blob/master/Backend/code/DataAccess/IDataAccess.cs

MongoDataAccess: https://github.com/peymanmortazavi/Hangout/blob/master/Backend/code/DataAccess/MongoDB/MongoDataAccess.cs

Thanks

Comment: Well, you'd need to translate every possible mutation in C# to one that can be represented in MongoDB updates, e.g. `a += 4` => `$inc : { a : 4 }`. That could be catastrophically complicated and impossible for many possible instructions, esp. those that depend on a itself or that use some method call, trig method, etc. The idea of 'swapping' out a database, particularly a NoSQL database which is supposed to be *specialized* to solve a particular problem, seems foolish to me in general, I must say -sorry. In a word: why?

Comment: I disagree, converting every mutation in C# to MongoDB Query language is already done by MongoDB's .Net library through support of LINQ. All we need here is to create a MongoUpdate which is a .Net class to pass to the Mongo driver so it automatically converts all those expressions to Mongo's javascript query language.

Comment: @mnemosyn to answer your second question, we have customers who want to use their own choice of database software (mostly NoSQL databases though). Thus, we need to have some database drivers to inject to the backend application.